# TextView is null

Tags: java, android, getview

I'm having a problem with TextView. After pressing a button I want to append something to that TextView but apparently is null all the time.

fragment_one.xml

```
....
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/reply"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/reply"/>
<Button android:text="@string/_0"
        android:id="@+id/_0"
        android:onClick="handleButtons"/>
....
```

ActivityTwo.java

```
....
public void handleButtons(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_one);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reply);
    if(v.getId() == R.id._0){
        tv.append("hi");
    }
....
```

I want to append some text to the `reply` TextView but apparently, it returns NullPointerException all the time. I am lost, I don't know what is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not use v.findViewById, but this.findViewById

Comment: This partly works. On ActivityTwo.java I create a new Instance of a Fragment. When doing this the fragment disappears.

Answer (score 0):

> TextView is null

Declare your TextView variable as global and intialize it in the onCreate()

Try this code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reply);

    }
    public void handleButtons(View v){

        if(v.getId() == R.id._0){
            tv.append("hi");
        }


    }
```